# Проблема кодировки при переносе БД на другой сервер

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql, cms, mysql

Есть работающий сайт на `ImageCMS`, который нужно перенести на другой хостинг. Соответственные файлы были успешно скопированы, осталось только перенести базу данных. На работающем сайте кодировка базы — `utf8_unicode_ci`, таблиц в ней — `utf8_general_ci`. Через `phpMyAdmin` был произведён экспорт базы в `UTF-8` и, соответственно, импорт на другой сайт в той же конфигурации. В результате кодировка в самой базе даных такая, как и нужна, значения полей идентично соответственным в оригинальной базе.

Проблема заключается в том, что `CMS` перестала воспринимать БД и на сайте вместо кирилицы выводятся либо пустые строки, либо ���. Думаю, проблема в настройках кодировки на сервере или где-то ещё, но не могу понять, где. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, проблема в настройках сервера, метод решения специфический и, видимо, исправляется методами исходного кода `CMS`, а именно дописыванием строчки:

```
$con->exec("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

[Источник](http://wiki.imagecms.net/Ошибки_при/после_установки#.D0.9D.D0.B0_.D1.84.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B5_.D0.BD.D0.B5_.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B0.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.81.D1.8F_.D0.BA.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B0).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить принудительно кодировку htaccess

Comment: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: Так же проверьте вот это 
config/database.php

$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

Comment: Нужно смотреть везде и привести все к одному

Comment: В `htaccess` прописана директива "`AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`".